# Using claims for application preferences

Tags: c#, .net, claims-based-identity

I'm building a web application that uses claims identity for the users.
My web app has a (small) number of user preference settings, such as application UI language.

Would it be bad practice to store a setting like this in a custom user claim? This is not strictly a claim, but technically the claims mechanism is well suited for these type of settings.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this. I've been doing this for years now and have not had a problem.

Comment: Why store preferences in a cookie? You'll probably only need it in the backend (where you can cache it as well). And in case of a SPA, request the preferences once and use other options to cache it client side. That claims are persisted in a cookie doesn't mean you should use it for this. When you change the storage mechansim, e.g. switch from cookie to JWT access token, then this willl backfire because a JWT can't be changed. Bottom line, preferences are not part of identity, so don't mis-use it just because you can. From a design perspective this is bad practice. Regardless if this works.

Answer (score 2):

Saving the application UI language in the token will result in the following: The user changes the UI language and this will most likely trigger a call to the database and save the data there, but the token contains the old value, so this won't update automatically(dynamically), it will update on the next login or token generation.

So is this a bad practice? No, it is not, it depends on your application and how dynamic you want it to be. If you generate a new token on App login, you can do the following - when the user changes the language, give him a "pop up" kind of message that this will take effect when the app is restarted or a button restart, that will generate a new token.

And again this depends on how you check what language the UI should be. If it checks from the token, the above could be done.

Comment: Just regenerate the cookie when the setting is changed - simples. With possibly changing the security stamp.

Comment: Yes even better, depends on how it's written :)